# Запуск Java-приложения с аргументами командной строки через bat-файл

Tags: java, bat

Есть maven-проект, собран jar, приложение запускается через командную строку и принимает аргументы.

Как правильно написать bat-файл чтобы запускаться с терминала с аргументами?

Answer (score 2):

```
cd C:\path\to\project
java -jar project.jar param1 param2
```